# mixed logit model r-package

Tags: r, multinomial-distribution, mlogit

I am using the mixed logit model implemented in R to estimate coefficients for the model. However, I am not sure which parameters I should define as random and which as not. Also, is it possible to define mixed nested model in R, because some attributes are correlated?

The problem is as follows. People should choose between two options (stairs and lifts), where alternatives have some generic attributes (quick and safe) and some alternative specific. All attributes can take either 1 or 0 value.

These are the utility functions:

[image: These are the utility functions:]

This is sample of the data:

[image]

```
structure(list(mode = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L), .Label = c("lift", "stair"), class = "factor"), part = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), rfloor = c(15L, 15L, 35L, 35L, 55L, 
55L, 15L, 15L, 35L, 35L, 55L, 55L, 15L, 15L, 35L, 35L, 55L, 55L, 
15L, 15L, 35L, 35L, 55L, 55L), choice = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L), safe = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), quick = c(1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), cont = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), altSpec1.s = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), altSpec1.l = c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("mode", "part", "rfloor", 
"choice", "safe", "quick", "cont", "altSpec1.s", "altSpec1.l"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -24L))
```

I used `mlogit` package to test the data, but as I mentioned I am not sure which parameters are random which not.

This is the code:

```
ModelData <- mlogit.data(data=Mlogitquestionnaire, choice='choice', shape='long', alt.var='mode', id.var='part')

mixedlogit <- mlogit(choice ~ safe + quick + cont + altSpec1.s + altSpec1.l, ModelData, rpar = c(safer='n', quicker='n'), halton=NA, R=100)
```

Comment: Please use `dput()` to show your data!

Answer (score 1):

The decision of which parameters to be random is less a statistical/programming question and more an economic theory question. The idea behind allowing for random variables in a choice model is to capture unobserved preference heterogeneity. For example, if you believe that different people have different preferences for using stairs, then this variable should not be fixed. You can use a discrete distribution (e.g. a latent class framework) or a continuous distribution (e.g. random parameter logit). The choice of distribution is based on your beliefs about how preferences are distributed, e.g. normal, lognormal, triangular.

To my knowledge, the `mlogit` package does not allow for nested mixed logit models, but you can induce correlation between the distribution of random parameters by allowing the off-diagonal elements of the lower Cholesky matrix to be non-zero. Specifically, set `correlation = TRUE`.